# c# Why won't the sum of variables from different classes amount in my code?

Tags: c#

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name = "asfd";
        int plhp = 100, plmp = 100, zenhp = 500;
        Random rdn = new Random();
        int atk = rdn.Next(10, 55);
        int zatk = rdn.Next(20, 35);

        while (plhp > 0 && zenhp > 0)
        {
            string action = Console.ReadLine();
            if (String.Equals(action, "attack", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                zenhp -= atk;
                Console.WriteLine("Zen has taken -" + atk.ToString() + " damage!");
                actionofzen(plhp, name, zenhp, zatk);
                Console.WriteLine("Your next move?");
            }
            else if (!(action == "attack" ))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid command.");
            }
        }
    }
    public static int actionofzen(int plhp, string name, int zenhp, int zatk)
    {
        Random rdn = new Random();
        string[] zenmoves = { "attack" };
        string zenaction = zenmoves[rdn.Next(zenmoves.Length)];
        if (zenaction == "attack")
        {
            plhp -= zatk;
            Console.WriteLine("Zen has countered, inflicting -" + zatk + " damage on " + name + ".");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem is that whenever Zen does something, it doesn't affect the overall HP, like the `plhp -= zatk;` doesn't even do anything, only the player can affect Zen's health. How do I make these variables from different classes sum up? Also how do I simplify this while maintaining the use of `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`?

```
if (action.Equals("attack", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
    action.Equals("heal", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass value by referance. so it can update the changes in the main method. Jus t pass the plhp with `ref` keyword Here is the working fiddle for it https://dotnetfiddle.net/amHbXF

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        string name = "asfd";
        int plhp = 100, plmp = 100, zenhp = 500;
        Random rdn = new Random();
        int atk = rdn.Next(10, 55);
        int zatk = rdn.Next(20, 35);
        while (plhp > 0 && zenhp > 0)
        {
            string action = Console.ReadLine();
            if (String.Equals(action, "attack", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                zenhp -= atk;
                Console.WriteLine("Zen has taken -" + atk.ToString() + " damage!");
                actionofzen(ref plhp, name, zenhp, zatk);
                Console.WriteLine("Player HP: " +plhp);
                Console.WriteLine("Zen HP: " +zenhp);
                Console.WriteLine("Your next move?");

            }
            else if (!(action == "attack"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid command.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static int actionofzen(ref int plhp, string name, int zenhp, int zatk)
    {
        Random rdn = new Random();
        string[] zenmoves =
        {
        "attack"
        }

        ;
        string zenaction = zenmoves[rdn.Next(zenmoves.Length)];
        if (zenaction == "attack")
        {
            plhp -= zatk;
            Console.WriteLine("Zen has countered, inflicting -" + zatk + " damage on " + name + ".");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx for info on what is going on with plhp. In order for modifications to plhp to propagate back up to the caller, it must be passed as a ref type. Your code is passing it as a "copy" (the default for value types), meaning you can change it all you want in actionofzen and the caller will never see the changes. plhp will have the same value it had before you called the method.

I'm not aware of any way to simplify the string comparison. You could downcase both strings and just use the == operator, but I'm not sure that is simpler.

Comment: downcasing both strings and doing == requires two extra strings to be created in memory, doing `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is the preferred option.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Look at the question, he's calling methods classes. I don't think it makes any difference if you create more or less strings in memory :)